# How to fix flicker effect when trying to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 elements which are set to position fixed, if they reach the bottom of the page the position element is then set back to static using javascript.

I have an issue when i try to scroll by clicking the scrollbar and dragging it. If you scroll all the way to the bottom normally, then if you try to click the scrollbar and drag it up. It flickers and stops me from scrolling.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ofcss1w/2/)

**HTML**

```
<header>This is the header</header>
<main>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <section id="fixed-elements">
        <div id="fix1">Fixed Footer2</div>
        <div id="fix2">Fixed Footer1</div>
    </section>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('#fixed-elements').css({
            'position': 'static',
                'bottom': 'auto',
        });
    } else {

       $('#fixed-elements').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '0',
        });            
    }
});

});
```

**CSS**

```
footer, header {
    background-color:green;
}
#content {
    height:1000px;
}
#fixed-elements {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

What's happening here? And how can i fix it? ( I think something similar happens when trying to scroll using middle mouse click ).

Comment: it seems like you dont have the problem in the specified fiddle.

Comment: @Lal edited my question to try an explain it a little better.

Comment: @Lal the issue is there especially if you scroll by clicking the scroll bar and moving slowly up.

Comment: sorry...i'm not getting what you are saying..

Comment: applying the style at the bottom of the scroll makes the scroll bar go away, which causes a scroll, which re-applies the code that fires when scrolling all the way to the bottom. one big loop.

Comment: @dandavis if that were the case why does it work when scrolling with the wheel and not clicking on the scroll bar?

Comment: I think the fixed element doesn't contribute to the document height, but static items do. Pretty much @dandavis is saying then happens

Comment: if you scroll up more than the height of the fixed elements, then you side-step the ambiguous part that sometime is and sometimes aint the same as the document height.

Comment: @dandavis So what is the solution here? I don't think it's possible to take into account the ambiguous part?

Comment: well, you don't really want to change the height during scroll, for now-obvious reasons. i think the simplest solution would be to simply add space to the bottom so that your real footer can visually appear over the fixed footer when scrolling all the way down, maybe something akin to `footer{padding-bottom: 2em;}`

Comment: @dandavis Hmm, this is not really a solution i was looking for. The main problem is defiantly the flickering. I am just wondering if there is another way i can do go about this. As the problem exists on a mobile device as well which is frustrating.

Comment: @dandavis I came across this plugin which does this. https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed. It works well http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/2430/. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done without static, but with the recalculated value bottom:

```
'bottom': $('footer').outerHeight(true) + (($('body').outerHeight(true) - $('body').outerHeight())/2),
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rbz16Lpp/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ofcss1w/6/). It accomplishes what you want without the flickering.

Basically, once you scroll to the top of the footer, it sets the position of the `#fixed-elements` to absolute, relative **to the bottom of `main`, which has `position: relative`**.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totalHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
        footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop(), (totalHeight - footerHeight));
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (totalHeight - footerHeight)) {
            $('#fixed-elements').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                 'bottom': 0
            });
        } else {

           $('#fixed-elements').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': 0
            });            
        }
    });

});
```

CSS (only one line was added):

```
/* you might consider removing padding and margin from the body,
   because it'll make it a little smoother
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} */

main {
    position: relative; // added this to main
}

footer, header {
    background-color:green;
}

#content {
    height:1000px;
}

#fixed-elements {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```